# conda export environment and package

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I want to export an environment AND its packages, using conda 4.10.

Reading the `conda` docs, it suggests exporting environments using `conda env export > environment.yml`. However, I am not sure if it is my problem (and if so, what the solution is), but there is no package information.

```
name: guest
channels:
  - defaults
prefix: C:\Anaconda3\envs\guest
```

After some googling, I learnt to export packages using `conda list --export > requirements.txt`. This time, there is no environment information.

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: win-64
ca-certificates=2021.5.30=h5b45459_0
certifi=2021.5.30=py38haa244fe_0
...
```

How do I export both into one file and use it? Or should I just export two files, create an environment first, and install the packages?

---

On a side note, how do I make my packages match `requirements.txt`, that is, to remove extra packages, install missing ones, and update/ downgrade to the specific version? Is there a command for this, or should I delete the whole environment and start from scratch?

Comment: There is something wrong - the first command should export both. Please redo these commands but include the `--name` argument to ensure that you are exporting the same environment.

Comment: @merv You actually solved my problem. Because I created the environment with PyCharm, and PyCharm creates nameless environments with only the path specified, by exporting with --prefix, it works.